# How many unanswered questions are on SO

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

"Unanswered" to be honest is "the answer(s) given are not upvoted by the community".
But I wanted to figure out the number of questions without any answer.
is it possible? how?
Searching for "answers:0" lists the Q's without any A's but shows not the number how many there are.

Comment: Actually, "unanswered" is exactly a **question with no upvoted answers**. It doesn't depend only on the person who asked, but also on the community who checked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be work-around by

- searching `answers:0`
- (page count-1) x page size + last_page_questions_count

There is 1051 pages and last page has 24 questions now (and I set 50 questions per page), so

- 50 * 1050 + 24 => 52524

Or

You might want to do feature-request for matched items count for search results too.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/search for more advanced search tips.

Answer (score 1):

Formulated a query at [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/246/)

```
create table #unanswered (Id int primary key)

insert #unanswered 
select q.Id  from Posts q
where (select count(*) from Posts a where a.ParentId = q.Id) = 0
and CommunityOwnedDate is null and ClosedDate is null and q.ParentId is null 
and AcceptedAnswerId is null​
```

The result:

> (40547 row(s) affected)

Comment: This uses the site definition of unanswerd - i.e. questions with no upvoted answers. The OP want questions with no (zero) answers at all.

Comment: @chrisF: edited.